# Sum Data Every 12 months ongoing (rolling)

Tags: google-sheets, sum, cumulative-sum

i'm new to google spreadsheet,
i'm trying to find a formula / app script from google but kinda hard to find for reference
i wish to do the condition where ;

1. Once the data is completed (12 months) it will sum up (consumption kWh, Cost) based on year where this sum value will be move to the next sheet (yearly data)
2. The process is ongoing (rolling)

here is the spreadsheet is used https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYOPObks9F8uOu4kuqqg6ETnCXzZFhY2Ra1AgAJJ9KA/edit#gid=328410064

thank you in advance

I've search everywhere but could't find the proper formula

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please make it public.

Comment: Okay, i've put it in public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your request, the data should be summed up based on the year.

Since the data will be accumulated on both sheets, check this formula that I tested

[image: Yearly Data]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Hospital Serian'!E2:E1000)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,'Hospital Serian'!A2:A1000))))
```

This will start summing the data based on the year you have in the cell (A3).

I have applied it to your sheet for both hospitals that you have had.

Check it out and tell me in case there's something else that I miss.

Comment: Is it possible for the year (Yearly Data) to auto-fill as well based on the data from the hospital? since I wanted it to keep rolling? for instance: The Yearly Data will be automatically updated without having me type it manually when new year data is available. Later I have to generate a graph for analysis on a yearly basis

Example:
Yearly Data
2023
2024
2025
etc ......

Something like this will automatically be updated inside the yearly data when new year data is available.

Comment: Yes, this is the simple part, you just need to drag the formula and add the years 

I have opened your sheet and applied that, check the cells and you will get my point.

Also, added another function to check if the year cell is empty to not add data to not make any confusion between it and the Search function 

So the final formula will be 

=if(A3<1,"", SUMPRODUCT(('Hospital Serian'!E2:E1000)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,'Hospital Serian'!A2:A1000))))

Comment: Can it be done without having to drag the formula? Like fully automated? Every time new data is added, then the data will be added as well inside the yearly data. 
Autofill (without dragging formula) in yearly data every time new data is added.

Comment: Yes Cyril, it's possible but we'll have to change the formula and do some workarounds. 
We'll have to separate the Year from the Month in both sheets with (Right) formula.
Then, we'll change the formula to be instead of (Sumproduct and Search) it will be just SUMIF.
To apply it without dragging it, we'll use (arrayformula) which is a powerful Google Spreadsheet formula that applies the formula on the desired cells. 
Here's the new formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(if(SUMIF('Hospital Serian'!G2:G,A3:A,'Hospital Serian'!E2:E)=0,"",(SUMIF('Hospital Serian'!G2:G,A3:A,'Hospital Serian'!E2:E))))

Comment: Almost there but I need the year to be added automatically as well when new data from (Hospital Serian / Hospital Lundu) is added, the year will be automatically added to the Yearly Data.